# How to optimize dockerfile to avoid stuck when stop a container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I wrote a dockerfile to build a clashserver in ubuntu container. However, when I tried to stop the container, the docker just got stuck. There is no any error code or any answer from the terminal.
I think some disharmony command appeared in the dockerfile.
This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get autoclean \


COPY clash-linux-amd64 /bin/clash_run

RUN mkdir  /etc/clash \
    && chmod +x /bin/clash_run 

EXPOSE 7890
EXPOSE 7891
EXPOSE 9090

CMD ["/bin/clash_run","-d","/etc/Clash/"]
```

If you want to pull the docker image:cfbsks/clash_ubuntu:v0.1

Comment: Sometimes this is caused by a process that doesn't react normally to a signal which is supposed to stop a process. Does clash server stop normally when run outside of Docker?

Comment: The tag you mention is not available. I guess you forgot to push it. I tested the available tag: cfbsks/clash_ubuntu:test and that one works fine. Starting and stopping the container works without any issue

Comment: @NickODell Usually, We stop the clash process by ctrl+c in ubuntu terminal, and nothing is unexpectation.

Comment: @Mihai Sorry about that,After checking I indeed forgot to push(fixed now). And one thing more important is we should map a volume to make the clash command work. Container path is `/etc/Clash/`.Your host path need this file:[link](https://github.com/Dreamacro/maxmind-geoip/releases/download/20220912/Country.mmdb).

Comment: If the issue doesn't appear, you should wait the clash server for initializing

Comment: The clash server is used as a proxy server. If some connections were not terminated, when we stop the container, will the issue begins here? And how to fix it?

Comment: That `CMD` construct should cause your service to run as the only process in the container, and commands like `docker stop` will send it SIGTERM and eventually SIGKILL in a pretty normal way.  Is your application code handling these signals?  The Dockerfile seems fine but I don't think it's actually enough information to understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze I didn’t study the SIGTERM and SIGKILL. And obviously that application didn’t made specific compatible changes for those signals. The application is [link](https://github.com/Dreamacro/clash) if you need. Please tell more about those signals like how to handle them.